# link value of cell in last column to inserted text box (via vba)

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, reference, textbox

I'm trying to create a dynamic chart title by inserting a text box in the chart title that displays the value of the last populated cell in column A. The number of rows increases over time, so I'm trying to come up with a dynamic cell reference. When I hover over the text box a tool tip appears with this text "TextBox 2" so I assume that is the name of the text box. I'm definitely open to other methods that do not use vba. It seems that none of this code can activate the text box:

```
Sub textbox()
Worksheets("Figure3-5").TextBoxes("TextBox 2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
End Sub

Sub textbox()
Worksheets("Figure3-5").TextBox2.Value = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
End Sub

Sub textbox()
ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 2").Select
Selection.Characters.Text = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Comment: use [`=OFFSET()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php)

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Sheets("Figure3-5").Select
    Sheets("Figure3-5").Shapes("TextBox 2").Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
End Sub
```

**Edit#1:**

To get the *Names* of *Shapes* on the sheet run:

```
Sub Namer()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In Sheets("Figure3-5").Shapes
        MsgBox s.Name
    Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get a "Run-time error'-2147024809: The item with the specified name wasn't found." I just cant figure out how to pinpoint the actual name of the text box it seems. I don't see how it would be any other name than the one that appears in the tool tip when I hover over the text box.

Comment: Perhaps is has to do with the text box being on the chart.

Comment: The only name that is returned is the chart name.

Comment: No prob, maybe I have to somehow reference/activate the chart and chart title as well?

Comment: Through a lot of trial and error I got this code to work: `Worksheets("Figure3-5").ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate` 
`ActiveChart.Shapes("TextBox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value`